# Why does adding a print statement cause my multi-touch listener to start working?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, multi-touch

```
function multitouchHandler(event)

    if ( "began" == event.phase ) then
        myTable[event.target.id] = true
    end

    if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
      if thisObject == currentObject then
         removeObject()   
      else
         print("This object isn't the current object.")
         endProgram()
      end
    end
end
```

This is a multi-touch event handler that is called by two objects being touched at the same time. The code works and does what I want it to do, but I'm not sure why.

It actually started working when I got frustrating not knowing what was wrong so I added `print()` statements throughout my entire project to help me troubleshoot. To my surprise when I added the `print()` statements, multi-touch started working.

One by one I removed them until I figured out which one was actually causing my multi-touch listener to start working and it turns out to be the one in the above code. If I take out the `print()` statement, multi-touch stops working.

This isn't the exact code in my program, but it's summarized to act like the listener. I would like to know why the print() statement is needed. It seems to add a long enough 'pause' to make the multi-touch return the `if thisObject == currentObject` condition to true, but if that's the case then I would think there is a better way to create this pause.

(`currentObject` is chosen by two objects being touched and then compared to the `currentObject`)

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy, there is nothing like what you said.If your using multitouch, please check whether your using `system.activate("multitouch")`. If you need a pause use timer to make some delay and the call the function. Make sure you are removing the timer while exiting.